# Expansion // Explosion and Alms Collector

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have an [Alms Collector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAlms%20Collector%5d) and my opponent casts [Explosion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bExplosion%5d) where X is 4 targeting himself and my Alms Collector, should Alms Collector still replace the draw 4 effect?

I assume because Alms Collector doesn't leave the battlefield until state based actions are checked and that won't happen until after Explosion fully resolves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, Alms Collector will replace Explosion's draw effect, for the reason you mentioned.**

The exact order of events is like this:

1. Explosion starts resolving.
2. Explosion deals 4 damage to Alms Collector.
3. Your opponent would draw 4 cards as the result of Explosion's second instruction, but Alms Collector replaces that effect. Instead, you and your opponent each draw 1 card.
4. Explosion finishes resolving and goes to the graveyard.
5. State-based actions are checked. Alms Collector dies because it has lethal damage marked on it.
6. The active player gains priority.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct; you will still get the replacement effect.

State based actions will not be checked until after Explosion fully resolves. So while Explosion is resolving, Alms Collector will have 4 damage, but it (and its static ability) will still be around. When Alms Collector has your opponent draw 4 cards, that effect will be replaced by you and your opponent each drawing a card. Then after Explosion resolves, state based actions are checked and Alms Collector will die.